# Duo API Bash Call

Tags: python, bash, shell, api, curl

I'm trying to use Curl to perform a call with the DUO API.

I tried reviewed their docs here: https://duo.com/docs/adminapi#authentication

The docs says to pass the creds as HMAC key for the request but now sure how to get that going.

This is what I got so far:

```
curl --request GET \
     --header 'Authorization: Basic 'Integration key:Secret key'' \
     --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
     "https://api-12345678.duosecurity.com/auth/v2/check"
```

Which returns

```
{"code": 40101, "message": "Missing request credentials", "stat": "FAIL"}
```

Can one point me to the right direction for an example in Bash. If not in Python.

Comment: Something doesn't look right in this sequence of quotes: `'Authorization: Basic 'Integration key:Secret key''`

Comment: Same sequence of quotes worked on another API not from Duo. Perhaps duo api dont like this

Comment: But the first header content is `"Authorization: Basic"` followed by _nothing,_ because `Integration key:Secret key''` is outside the header. I was wondering if that was a copy/paste typo into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your request format does not seem correct, because `Integration key:Secret key''` is outside the header (look at the way the syntax is highlighted in the question).

Try:

```
curl --request GET \
     --header 'Authorization: Basic' \
     --header 'Integration key: Secret key' \
     --header 'Date: Tue, 21 Aug 2012 17:29:18 -0000' \
     --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
     "https://api-12345678.duosecurity.com/auth/v2/check"
```

It's somewhat uncommon to have header names with a space and a lowercase like `Integration key`, so you may need to experiment with variants, like `Integration-Key`.

**Second**, the `401xx` series errors [mean](https://help.duo.com/s/article/1338?language=en_US):

> 401 The “Authorization”, “Date”, and/or “Content-Type” headers were missing or invalid.

You'll need to add the missing the `Date` header, required by the [authenticator](https://duo.com/docs/adminapi#authentication).

Comment: thanks for you help man. I tried the updated syntax and still got {"code": 40101, "message": "Missing request credentials", "stat": "FAIL"}

Comment: @AmadoTejada Oh, you're missing a Date header. Updated.

Comment: Deff getting close to that 200 code but I got again `{"code": 40101, "message": "Missing request credentials", "stat": "FAIL"}` when using the updated syntax. The docs shows to use the Integration-key as the username and the secret-key in a different format.  HMAC-SHA1 if im not mistaking

Comment: @AmadoTejada I'm afraid I don't know, then. Please post your answer once you figure it out. Good luck :)

Comment: @AmadoTejada Feel free to +1 if it was a bit useful, or not, if it wasn't :) But do come back and post your own answer and accept it once you get the format correct. It will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles on this, here's what I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash -u

FORM="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
NOW=$(date -R)

#get these from the Duo Admin interface
INT="<integration key>"
KEY="<secret passcode>"
API="<api host>.duosecurity.com"

URL="/auth/v2/check"
REQ="$NOW\nGET\n$API\n$URL\n"

#could also use awk here, or the --binary mode as suggested elsewhere
HMAC=$(echo -n "$REQ" | openssl sha1 -hmac "$KEY" | cut -d" " -f 2)

AUTH=$(echo -n "$INT:$HMAC" | base64 -w0)

curl -s -H "Date: $NOW" -H $FORM -H "Authorization: Basic $AUTH" https://$API$URL
```

Running this yields:

> {"response": {"time": 1539726254}, "stat": "OK"}

Reference: [Duo Api docs section on authentication](https://duo.com/docs/authapi#-authentication-)

Comment: For me, it only worked after I changed the REQ to actual newlines in my Bash script. Thanks for the example though!